# Maven time out on Central Repository - No Proxy setting - Windows

Tags: java, maven

**Maven throws time out when try to clean the project**

```
USER>mvn clean
```

**After this command the build throw:**

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dep
endencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apac
he.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apa
che.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven
.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org
/23.235.46.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException
```

Comment: Can you `ping` `repo.maven.apache.org`? If so, can you access it via browser?

Comment: Ping statistics for 23.235.46.215: Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Comment: What about the browser? Via HTTPS

Comment: It is working, but I need to inject dependencies from command line.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure what could be causing this. You may have a proxy on unintentionally, or you may have a firewall which is blocking particular applications (in this case, Maven) from accessing particular websites

Comment: How can I check if my firewall is blocking it?, i tear down the windows firewall and is not working.

Comment: Honestly, someone else may be able to better help you at this point. I've exhausted my list of go-to possible causes for this issue and I'm as stumped as you are now :-P

Comment: Any progress? I see the same timeout for repo.maven.apache.org:443. If I run 'netstat' while maven is hung, just before it times out, netstat shows 23.235.46.215 in a SYN_SENT state, which suggests a firewall blocking access to it, but I haven't found which one that would be.

Comment: I created a new project and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any other repositories configured in your ${HOME}/.m2/`settings.xml` (or pom.xml)?  If so, make sure that none of them have the id of `central` or you may have reconfigured the location of maven-central.

Also, if you use a locally hosted "proxy" maven repository, do not reconfigure `central` to point to the locally hosted maven repository, instead use a "mirror" directive, configuring the repository to be something with an id like "localrepo" and specifying it as a "mirrorOf" `central`.

Finally, avoid any "proxy" settings unless you want all of your searches to start searching for repositories outside of your network (aka on the internet).

Maven manages dependencies in a very specific manner, which provides repeat-ability of builds.  Basically it needs to be encoded in the pom.xml.  Yes, you can do some magic to pass such things through using the command line, but if you do that, you are working against the design of maven (and robbing yourself of most of it's utility at the same time).

If you need something to "update" a build, consider making a script that updates and checks in the pom.xml for the artifact, or  (less ideal) base the dependency on a snapshot version.

Comment: I have not a proxy setting in my computer, It is new and it is personal.